# How to find out what people say when you cannot make out the words?

Tags: listening, transcription

Are there some online resources to help with understanding the audio when transcript is not available?

For example, [here](https://youtu.be/mIBg-w6TNLE?t=107) the host replies: 'Yeah, you might get caught ...... people', and I cannot make out what is between 'caught' and 'people' even after listening dozens of times. How can I find it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He actually says "you don't want to get caught in a Home Depot".

Home Depot is the name of a popular home improvement retailer in the United States.

The guest on the show already mentioned at 1m35s that they were going to 'Home Depot' to buy an air conditioning unit, so you had, in fact, heard the name already. Perhaps it was clearer when she said it?

YouTube videos sometimes have closed captions available, although I believe these are auto-generated and are not always accurate. However, they don't appear to be available on this video.